# Find multiple memory sizes with regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have multiple kind of strings which represents the storage of phones.

One kind of string looks like this:

```
8 GB
```

Another like this:

```
8/16 GB
```

And another like this:

```
8/16/32 GB
```

And generally, like this:

```
number/number/number/.../number GB
```

but also

```
number GB
```

I would like to be able to get the different kind of memory storage possibilities. So for this:

`8/16 GB` -> I would like to get [8,16]

`8 GB` -> [8]

I am failing to see how could I do a regex that would contemplate those cases. So far I know how to do this:

```
/(\d+)\s+GB/.match(my_storage_text)
```

But I am not sure how to do the generalistic approach taking into account the cases where there are multiple numbers...

CLARIFICATION:

Let me state which kind of strings I can find..

`8 GB, 1 GB RAM` --> I would need something like `{:internal => {:size => [8], :units => 'GB'}, :ram => {:size => 1, :units => 'GB'}}`

`8/16/32 GB, 128 GB RAM` --> I would need something like `{:internal => {:size => [8,16,32], :units => 'GB'}, :ram => {:size => 128, :units => 'GB'}}`

`8/16/32 GB` --> I would need something like `{:internal => {:size => [8,16,32], :units => 'GB'}, :ram => nil}`

Comment: What language do you use for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a text like

```
subject = "8/16 GB; 512/1024 MB"
```

then you can use

```
/(\d+)(?=(?:\/\d+)*\s*([MG]B))/
```

to get an array of each number and corresponding unit:

```
irb(main):002:0> subject.scan(/(\d+)(?=(?:\/\d+)*\s*([MG]B))/)
=> [["8", "GB"], ["16", "GB"], ["512", "MB"], ["1024", "MB"]]
```

**Explanation:**

```
(\d+)       # Match a number, capture it in group 1
(?=         # Assert that the following can be matched here:
 (?:/\d+)*  # Any number of "slash, followed by number"s
 \s*        # followed by optional whitespace
 ([MG]B)    # followed by MB or GB, capture that in group 2
)           # End of lookahead assertion
```

Comment: Actually, I should have stated my question more correctly. I have edited my question with the kind of strings that I can get, but your answer will help me to build what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

change "/" to "," and add "[" and "]" after

```
1 step: s/\//,/g
2 step: s/(.*) GB/$1/
3 step: "[" + text + "]"
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using ruby to accomplish this.  Try:

```
# Match consecutive digits which are followed by a slash or a space
regexp = /(\d+)[\/ ]/

str1 = '8 GB'
str2 = '8/16 GB'
str3 = '8/16/32 GB'

str1.scan(regexp)    # => [["8"]]
str2.scan(regexp)    # => [["8"],["16"]]
str3.scan(regexp)    # => [["8"],["16"],["32"]]

# Since scan returns an array of single-element arrays,
# pare down the result to an array of strings .
str1.scan(regexp).map { |el| el[0] }   # => ["8"]
str2.scan(regexp).map { |el| el[0] }   # => ["8", "16"]
str3.scan(regexp).map { |el| el[0] }   # => ["8", "16", "32"]
```

**EDIT** *based on OP's comments*...

Try:

```
regexp = /(\d+|[a-zA-Z]+)/

teststrings = ['8 GB', '8/16 GB', '8/16/32 GB', '256/512 MB']

teststrings.each do |str| 
  storage = {}
  storage['size'] = []
  str.scan(regexp).each { |el| el[0].match(/\d+/) ? storage['size'].push(el[0].to_i) : storage['unit'] = el[0] }
  puts "#{str} RESULTS IN: #{storage}"
end
```

Result Output:

```
8 GB RESULTS IN: {"size"=>[8], "unit"=>"GB"}
8/16 GB RESULTS IN: {"size"=>[8, 16], "unit"=>"GB"}
8/16/32 GB RESULTS IN: {"size"=>[8, 16, 32], "unit"=>"GB"}
256/512 MB RESULTS IN: {"size"=>[256, 512], "unit"=>"MB"}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that what if there is no GB but MB?

Comment: True.  Good catch, @HommerSmith.  Based on the OP's post, I assumed (perhaps wrongly) that he would only be seeing GB.  It seems, at least until we see further information from OP, that he only cares about the numbers and not the units (which... may be an issue).

Comment: I am actually the OP :) I should have stated that yes, the units might vary.

Comment: Ooh, oops.  I should have read more carefully.  So then, if the string is something like `8/16/32 GB`, then you probably would want to capture something like [{ size: '8', unit: 'GB'}, { size: '16', unit: 'GB'}, { size: '32', unit: 'GB'}].  But how might your input string look for something like `256/512 MB, 1/2/4/8 GB` ?

Comment: Actually for this: 1/2/4/8 GB I would like to get {size: [1,2,4,8], unit: 'GB'} You know?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

This will match all this possibilities

8/16/32 GB,8/16 GB and 8 GB

```
/(\d+)\/?(\d+)?\/?(\d+)?\/?\sGB/
```

[click here to see](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/3Ll)